# Exceptions thrown by spring-aop

Tags: java, spring-aop

I am invoking a method from within an AOP (Spring) (Around advice). 
Once the method returns i do some checking on the object and if i am not happy with the results i throw an exception (my own). However, when the aspect returns, instead of my exception i get an "UndeclaredThrowableException"
Any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException.html) for `UndeclaredThrowableException` it mentions that this occurs due to the the fact that a checked exception is being thrown that is not expected by the method signature that you are using as a joinpoint.

The way it appears you should deal with this situation is to make the exception that you are throwing a Runtime exception (extends [Runtime Exception](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)).

Its worth noting you seem to be able to access the original exception like so:

```
try {
    ...
}
catch(UndeclaredThrowableException e) {
    e.getUndeclaredThrowable();
}
```

However I reckon that is the wrong way to go about solving the problem you are having.

Comment: Been there, done that.. but it is not i'm looking for. i want to catch the actual exception without having to go through this boilerplate